# RMI Replication EhCache

Tags: replication, rmi, ehcache

I am working on ehcache replication using RMI for the first time. I am not able to get pass through  the below error.

The root cause from the below stack trace shows:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: net.sf.ehcache.distribution.RMICachePeer_Stub (no security manager: RMI class loader disabled)
```

I am using jdk1.6.0_16 with weblogic 12c and I have already tried below ways but didnt get any success.

1. Added the ehcache jar to the classpath. set CLASSPATH=%CLASSPATH%;C:\Oracle\Middleware\wlserver_12.1\server\lib\ehcache-2.8.3.jar;
2. set JAVA_OPTIONS=%JAVA_OPTIONS% -Djava.security.manager -Djava.security.policy==C:/Oracle/Middleware/wlserver_12.1/server/lib/weblogic.policy -Djava.rmi.server.codebase=file:///C:/Oracle/Middleware/wlserver_12.1/server/lib/ehcache-2.8.3.jar
3. set the System.setSecurityManager(new RMISecurityManager()) on the application startup.

Any help is appreciated.

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.cache.CacheException: net.sf.ehcache.CacheException: Problem starting listener for RMICachePeer //localhost:40001/com.wipro.dms.digi.domain.Location. Initial cause was
RemoteException occurred in server thread; nested exception is: 
java.rmi.UnmarshalException: error unmarshalling arguments; nested exception is: 
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: net.sf.ehcache.distribution.RMICachePeer_Stub (no security manager: RMI class loader disabled)
```

Comment: The remark in the message about the security manager is parenthetical. It isn't itself the cause of the problem. The problem you should be investigating is the `ClassNotFoundException.`

Comment: Hey EJP, Thanks for the reply. The class net.sf.ehcache.distribution.RMICachePeer_Stub exists in the ehcache-2.8.3.jar which is in the classpath. Continuously getting "no security manager: RMI class loader disabled". Do I need to check if the rmiregistry is runningon my weblogic. If yes how should I do that?

Comment: That JAR file needs to be on the CLASSPATH of the Registry as well as of the server and client. Easiest solution to that is `LocateRegistry.createRegistry()`.